# Debugging a template that causes Bus error (core dumped)

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code which contains a template named FromString that takes a string and converts it to the type of the second argument:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template<typename Type_t>
inline Type_t FromString(const string& S, Type_t& T)
  {
   istringstream sin(S);
   sin>>T; 
   return T;
  }

int main () {

   string words = "52";
   int number = 0;

   FromString(words, number);

   cout << number << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

This piece of code works both on my PC and server.

When I try to use this template in a much bigger code, it works fine on my personal PC but when I compile and run it on a server some instances of the FromString work and others cause the following error:

```
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I tried looking at the type of the two parameters, S and T but they do not seem abnormal when the error arises.

What steps would you advise I take in order to identify the source of the problem ?

Not sure if this is important but I have `gcc version 5.4.0` on my PC and `gcc version 4.8.5` on my server.

Thanks for any help,

#### [Edit]

The gdb debuger gives me the following output:

```
Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
basic_istringstream (__mode=std::_S_in, __str="mystring", this=0x7fffffff8a50, __in_chrg=<optimized out>, __vtt_parm=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:328
328       : __istream_type(), _M_stringbuf(__str, __mode | ios_base::in)
```

#### [Edit 2]

I've managed to narrow it down to a problem with `istringstream`

```
(gdb) print __str
$7 = "mystring"
(gdb) print this
$8 = (std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > * const) 0x7fffffff8a50
```

But the input string seems correct,

Comment: Pass references instead of values. Then you don't need to return a copy of `T`.

Comment: Did your debugger provide any insight?

Comment: @StoryTeller Oups my bad, I copied the code from a non working version, even with references I still get the error. I edited my question

Comment: @tadman I added the output of the debugger as an edit

Comment: You should inspect core dump, look at stack trace, figure out which template fails, with which arguments.

Comment: So it seams you failed to parse the "mystring" value - could you show the sample code that actually tries to parse it with actual types used during parse?